# Sum multiple columns, based on distinct values in different Columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have the following table, in an Azure SQL DB that has duplicate values that I'm trying to Sum.

Here is the Logic: If the PaymentID is unique, then Sum Payment,
If the creditID is unique, then sum credit,
if the debitid is unique, then sum debit.
And take the max(source)
The idea is to get a single line, per ID with distinct values for the ID summed.

| id | payment | credit | debit | Source | paymentid | creditid | debitid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1510142123 | -589.53 | 0 | 0 | CC | 5831879 | NULL | NULL |
| 1510142123 | -589.53 | 0 | 0 | CC | 5831882 | NULL | NULL |
| 1510142123 | -155.06 | 0 | 0 | CC | 5898896 | NULL | NULL |
| 157771145 | -126.42 | 0 | 0 | CC | 5885900 | NULL | NULL |
| 157771145 | -58.73 | 0 | 0 | CC | 5885903 | NULL | NULL |
| 158088837 | -55.14 | 0 | -3.45 | CC | 5897306 | NULL | 5897303 |
| 158088837 | -5.75 | 0 | -3.45 | CC | 5897309 | NULL | 5897303 |
| 158464166 | -161 | 0 | -3.45 | CC | 5910551 | NULL | 5910548 |
| 158464166 | -24.15 | 0 | -3.45 | CC | 5910554 | NULL | 5910548 |
| 1591970734 | -111.61 | 0 | 0 | Bank | 5939648 | NULL | NULL |
| 1591970734 | -0.01 | 0 | 0 | Cash | 5939711 | NULL | NULL |
| 1591970734 | -0.01 | 0 | 0 | Cash | 5939714 | NULL | NULL |
| 159297565 | -708.93 | 20 | 0 | CC | 5943728 | 5910848 | NULL |
| 159297565 | -0.02 | 20 | 0 | Cash | 5948207 | 5910848 | NULL |

For example:

158464166 | -185.15 | 0 | -3.45 | CC | 5910551 | 5910548

(in the above - I've taken the min(paymentid) to make it look nicer

Please note that although in the above snippet, Creditid and Debitid only have a duplicate ID, it's possible that they may have distinct IDs, so any code will have to be able to handle that. PaymentID will always be unique.

It is also possible that the values for payment, credit and debit may not be unique (e.g. a payment of $50 is made twice to a single ID), so we can't group on payment.

I got as far as this:

```
SELECT id, sum(payment), sum(credit), sum(debit), max(source), creditid, debitid  
FROM (  
  SELECT *,  
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS cnt  
  FROM Temp_Payment) AS t  
WHERE t.cnt > 1  

group by id, creditid, debitid
```

but it's not giving the expected outcome.

Comment: Can you explain once again in other word ? This is not clear, "f the PaymentID is unique, then Sum Payment , If the creditID is unique, then sum credit" can yu give example of calculation ?No need to write SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one row you posted expected results for, this will return what you want.

In the future, please [post your table as an insert script](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) so that it's easier to work with.

```
SELECT
    x.*
INTO #x
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1510142123,-589.53,0,0,'CC',5831879,NULL,NULL),
        (1510142123,-589.53,0,0,'CC',5831882,NULL,NULL),
        (1510142123,-155.06,0,0,'CC',5898896,NULL,NULL),
        (157771145,-126.42,0,0,'CC',5885900,NULL,NULL),
        (157771145,-58.73,0,0,'CC',5885903,NULL,NULL),
        (158088837,-55.14,0,-3.45,'CC',5897306,NULL,5897303),
        (158088837,-5.75,0,-3.45,'CC',5897309,NULL,5897303),
        (158464166,-161,0,-3.45,'CC',5910551,NULL,5910548),
        (158464166,-24.15,0,-3.45,'CC',5910554,NULL,5910548),
        (1591970734,-111.61,0,0,'Bank',5939648,NULL,NULL),
        (1591970734,-0.01,0,0,'Cash',5939711,NULL,NULL),
        (1591970734,-0.01,0,0,'Cash',5939714,NULL,NULL),
        (159297565,-708.93,20,0,'CC',5943728,5910848,NULL),
        (159297565,-0.02,20,0,'Cash',5948207,5910848,NULL)
)AS x (id,payment, credit, debit, [source], paymentid, creditid, debitid);

SELECT 
    x.id,
    SUM(DISTINCT y.payment) AS payment, 
    SUM(DISTINCT y.credit) AS credit, 
    SUM(DISTINCT y.debit) AS debit,
    MAX(x.source) AS source,
    MIN(x.paymentid) AS min_paymentid,
    MAX(x.debitid) AS max_debitid
FROM #x AS x
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        SUM(x2.payment) AS payment,
        SUM(x2.credit) AS credit,
        SUM(x2.debit) AS debit
    FROM #x AS x2
    WHERE x.id = x2.id
    AND   x.paymentid = x2.paymentid
    GROUP BY x2.id, 
             x2.creditid, 
             x2.debitid
) AS y
GROUP BY x.id
ORDER BY x.id;
```

Comment: Tested this on the real data set - works like a charm - could you clarify the logic for me so I understand a bit better as to what the script does, so I know for next time I've got a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get similar result by using FIRST_VALUE window function

```
    select id, sum(payment), debit, credit
    from 
    ( select id, 
            payment AS payment,
            FIRST_VALUE(credit) OVER (PARTITION BY id, creditid) as credit,
            FIRST_VALUE(debit) OVER (PARTITION BY id, debitid) as debit
        FROM x 
    ) t
        group by id ,credit, debit
    order by id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The similar query  for PostgreSQL

```
SELECT 
x.id,
SUM(DISTINCT y.payment) AS payment, 
SUM(DISTINCT y.credit) AS credit, 
SUM(DISTINCT y.debit) AS debit--,
MAX(x.source) AS source,
MIN(x.paymentid) AS min_paymentid,
MAX(x.debitid) AS max_debitid
FROM  x
left  join lateral
(
    select
        x2.id,
        x2.creditid, 
        x2.debitid,
        SUM(x2.payment) AS payment,
        min(x2.credit) AS credit,
        min(x2.debit) AS debit
     FROM x AS x2
     GROUP BY x2.id, 
         x2.creditid, 
         x2.debitid
 )  y on  x.id = y.id     
GROUP BY x.id
ORDER BY x.id;
```